# Объявление и исполнение функции внутри создания массива

Tags: php

Всем доброго. Такая задача (и не спрашивайте зачем):

Есть код который создает массив, предположим:

```
 $data = array(
     ‘sub_array’ => ...
 );
```

Есть внешний массив данных, который пришел ко мне из некого API.
Он должен попасть в элемент массива `sub_array` после обработки `foreach`’ом. Есть вариант создать внегнюю функцию, предположим

```
function parse_array($arrayAPI){
    foreach($arrayAPI as $item){
        $return[] = ...
    }
    return $return;
}
```

И воспользоваться ей при создании массива, тоесть:

```
 $data = array(
     ‘sub_array’ => parse_array($arrayAPI)
 );
```

Но я столкнулся с тем, что таких функций мне надо создать очень-очень много, и «инкапсулировать» их никак, так как массив данных приходящий из API вовсе не стандартизирован, и везде нужны разные значения при прокрутки `foreach`. Буквально устану придумывать названия функциям (шутка). Поэтому появилась идея:

**А можно ли воткнуть `foreach` прямо в создание массива?**

Например:

```
 $data = array(
     ‘sub_array’ => function parse_array($arrayAPI){...}
 );
```

Понятное дело, что данный пример - бред, но думаю вы меня поняли. Весь ангогугл пролазил, так ничего толкового и не нашел. Кто поможет решить такую задачку?

---

**UPD**
Пока ждал хоть какого либо фидбека на вопрос - успел придумать как можно создать одну функцию для обработки даже для такого не стандартизированного массива (чего не мог сделать несколько суток ранее), **но вопрос остается актуальным, и интерес не угас все равно.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в зависимости от версии `php` вы можете объявить и тем или иным способом  выполнить анонимную функцию.
Если в php 7 можно выполнить ее сразу после объявления:

```
$data = [
   'value' => (function(){ return [1,2,3]})(),
];
```

то для версий 5.х, придется использовать немного другие способы. Например, чтобы выполнить функцию сразу, можно использовать `call_user_func`:

```
$data = [
    'value' => call_user_func(function( return [1,2,3]; ))
 ];
```

Очевидно этот код будет выполнен сразу после "объявления" массива.
Второй вариант - отложенное выполнение с помощью `array_walk`. В принципе это даже более гибкое решение, ибо позволит выполнить не все функции, а только необходимые.

```
$data = [ 
    'value' => function(){ return [1,2,3]; }
];

array_walk_recursive($data, function(&$item){
     if(is_callable($item)) $item = $item();
});
```

Используя дополнительные параметры `callback`-метода функции `array_walk`, можно отфильтровать и выполнить только нужные методы:

```
$data = [
    'key1' => function(){ return [1,2,3]; },
    'key2' => function(){ return [4,5,6]; },
    'key3' => [
        'subkey' => function(){ return -1; },
    ]
];

$exec= ['key1', 'subkey'];

array_walk_recursive($data, function(&$f, $key) use ($exec){
    if(!in_array($key, $exec])) return;

    if(is_callable($f))  $f = $f();
});
print_r($data);
```

в данном примере будут выполнены только функции для ключей `key1` и `subkey`

Comment: Превосходно,  спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Нет, нельзя, это противоречит самой идее функций - один раз создаётся, много раз используется. А так вы заного будете её создавать каждый раз. Можете создать одну мега-функцию которая будет обрабатывать весь массив, но это противоречит идее что одна функция должна делать одно действие. И вообще много это сколько? 10, 100?

Comment: хм, ну да, противоречит, согласен. Тем не менее в JS  можно, на сколько я знаю, инициализировать и сразу же исполнять функцию. тот же `$.ready(function(){ ... });`. Или: может, можно запустить foreach с return... Во всяком случае - прочитайте UPD в вопросе:)

Comment: В JS  не силён но по части функций он больше возможностей чем PHP предоставляет ИМХО. По прежнему считаю что одна большая функция это выход для вас в данном случае.